# IsolatedStorage: Delete preferences in uninstaller?

Tags: c#, .net, isolatedstorage

Our application saves user preferences in isolated storage.

However,it's proving tricky to remove these files from our uninstaller!

I can enumerate all of the files in IsolatedStorage (using the MSDN example code), locate the ones that are related to our strongname key, and attempt to remove/delete them. Unfortunately, that's where it all falls apart:

> MaxSize is not defined for this store.
>   An operation was performed that
>   requires access to MaxSize. Stores
>   obtained using enumeration APIs do not
>   have a well-defined MaxSize, since
>   partial evidence is used to open the
>   store.

Can anyone help with this? I guess I could spend days trying to fake up some Evidence to allow the installer to act as an imposter, but there must be a better (quicker, cleaner) way?!

If not, I guess I'm heading back to the good old registry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anybody else ever wants to know the answer...

It appears the best solutions might be:

- Move the Isolated Storage code into a separate Assembly which can be called from both the main application and the uninstaller, so that they can both access the data.
- Add a means for executing the main application with a command line flag that instructs it to delete the Isolated Storage files and exit, then call it from the uninstaller.
- or save all this messing about and ditch Isolated Storage altogether