# IsolatedStorage, will they be cleared along with application uninstall?

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-phone-8.1, isolatedstorage, isolatedstoragefile

I'm writing a WP8.1 app and using IsolatedStorage to save some data. I wonder, does these data get cleared when the app is uninstalled by the user? Or there need some specific clean up code ?

How about that on Windows 8.1? I've seen some questions about not being able to delete IsolatedStorage data in uninstaller.
[IsolatedStorage: Delete preferences in uninstaller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1159850/isolatedstorage-delete-preferences-in-uninstaller)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The isolated storage is properly cleared when an app is uninstalled, you've got nothing to do.

The question you linked is about the desktop version of .NET, which works quite differently from the phone one.

Comment: Thanks, could you put any reference? Books or links. I've tried to search a bit myself, apparently I didn't do a good job.

Comment: @CodingSiberian I don't have any reference, but you can find on StackOverflow many people wondering how to keep data on the phone after the app is uninstalled (to implement a time-limited trial for instance). Precisely because an uninstalled app leaves no trace.